# Save and bind to the Id of a drop-down selection, but display the Value in Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material-5

This might be a stupid question with a very simple answer, but after a week of coding I feel fried and can't figure it out.

How can I bind to the Id of a selection, but display the string representation of the value? I.e., I have a drop-down that display the names of Customers, but I want to save the `Id` for DB purposes.

My selection item has two properties: `customer.Display` (Name), and `customer.Id`.

**How can I do the binding to save my Id to `[(ngModel)]="loadDataService.selectedLoad.CustomerId`, but display my Display in the drop-down (it already displays the Display, so that is covered):**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Search" id="CustomerId" name="CustomerId" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myCustomerSearchControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="loadDataService.selectedLoad.CustomerId" (keyup)="onCustomerSearch($event)">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customerArray" [value]="customer.Display">
        {{ customer.Display }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: `[value]="customer.Display"` should be `[value]="customer.Id"` ... Unless that's something else, because that really seems too easy

Comment: Hey trichetriche, jip, too easy ;). When I bind `[value]="customer.Id"`, it displays that value (Id) as the selected value in the input field. I.e., it show a GUID and not the user-friendly name. I am binding to my data service `[(ngModel)]="loadDataService.selectedLoad.CustomerId"` with the selected value. But with my setup, it is the `customer.Display` and not the `customer.Id`. *pulling my hair out* :D

Comment: Oh, I see your issue. Let me get to work and I'll handle that for you.

Comment: Thanks! i would really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the autocomplete, you have a `optionSelected` event. You need to use that to find your selected option.

```
<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="setServiceId($event)">
  ...
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Then, in your component, you must implement that function :

```
setServiceId(dislay: string) {
  const id = this.customerArray.find(c => d.Display === display).id;
  this.loadDataService.selectedLoad.CustomerId = id;
}
```

This way of doing assumes you have unique customer displays. If not, you will need to use this function, with the previous HTML + this HTML :

```
setServiceId(customer: any) {
  this.loadDataService.selectedLoad.CustomerId = customer.id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. i like where you are going with this, and I think it is close. I tried both methods, but the first seems to be the one. However, I had to make some changes, as I got an error: Cannot read property id of undefined. So modified the one line to the following: `const customer = this.customerArray.find(c => c.Display === display.option.value);` But this also updates my selected drop-down value to equal the Id. I.e., it changes the display from customer name to customer id.

Comment: That's because you bind your service value directly to your input with `[(ngModel)]="loadDataService.selectedLoad.CustomerId"`. You should create a variable in your component and use the `onSelected` output, like I showed you, to set the value of your service.

Comment: Jip, figured it out. I removed my [()] binding to make it work. Tx!